Seeing temperature jumps on MAX31827 via I2C
On several MAX31827 devices, we are seeing a temperature jump when passing through exactly one temperature: from 47.9375°C to 48.0000°C we see a jump to 32.0000 °C, and from 48.0000°C to 47.9375°C we see a jump to 63.9375°C. The bit pattern of those 4 temperatures is interesting:
48.0000°C / 0.0625 = 768  -> 0b0000 0011 0000 0000 -> 0x0300
63.9375°C / 0.0625 = 1023 -> 0b0000 0011 1111 1111 -> 0x03FF

47.9375°C / 0.0625 = 767  -> 0b0000 0010 1111 1111 -> 0x02FF
32.0000°C / 0.0625 = 512  -> 0b0000 0010 0000 0000 -> 0x0200

So it looks like from 47.9375°C to 48°C, the LSB 0xFF remains in the memory of the MAX31827, but the MSB is switched from 0x02 to 0x03. Could this be a hardware defect?

What does your I2C signals look like? How are you decoding them?

The I²C protocol reads (and writes) data byte-wise, i.e., eight bits at a time. You need to read two bytes to get the 12-bit value, and, apparently, the measured temperature changed between these two individual reads.
The datasheet does not mention any mechanism to determine whether a conversion is currently in progress in automatic sampling mode.
The fastest conversion rate is eight per second, and I²C accesses are much faster. So just read the value repeatedly until the last two values match. (This should never need more than three two-byte reads.)

The temperature jump always happens repeatably at 47.9375°C to 48.0000°C, to me this sounds like a different problem

The jump happens when both bytes change at the same, and you read one old byte and one new byte.

A lot of temperature sensors solve this by latching one byte while reading the other. Something like latching the high byte while reading the low. So you always need to read them in that order. But I scanned the MAX31827 data sheet and didn't find any text eluding to this behavior.

A more efficient protocol is to read the MSB, the LSB, and then the MSB again. If the MSBs match, you're done; otherwise, save the last MSB and read the LSB and MSB again. The MSBs should match this time, but repeat as needed.

@DaveTweed It is not possible to read the LSB alone; might as well read the entire 16 bits.

Really? Then it SHOULD be an atomic read of the 16-bit value. It sounds like the chip designers screwed up, and doing multiple reads until you get two the same is a work-around for that.

The MAX31827 data sheet cautions against the selection of incompatible conversion values. Specifically, against selecting too small of a conversion interval and too high a resolution:

When selecting resolutions and conversion rates, note that if the
resolution is 12-bits, avoid the 8 conversions per second rate. The
conversion time under these conditions can be longer than the time
available to complete a conversion. In this case, the conversion does
not complete, and the data from the last valid conversion result
remains in the temperature register.


We are using 4 conversions per second, thank you!

If that's safe (sounds like it is), you might try switching the byte order when reading the temperature register. Or follow @DaveTweed 's suggestion of repeated readings to verify you didn't miss a case where the LSB change from all ones to all zeros and caused the MSB to increment (or if the opposite happens).

@st2000 The byte order always is MSB first; this device has one register number for the entire 16-bit value.

Hum, this is starting to boil down to bad communications. It the I2C runs too long? Do you only have 1 set of pull ups? I2C was likely meant to only exist between chips on the same PCB. But people keep adding meters of wire to it.
